# Unknown error in Request filtering feature in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-8

I am facing a weird scenario, in IIS 8.5, when i click on Request filtering feature a dialog box opens with no error description.
Tried to add requestFiltering tag in web config still no success.

[image]

Comment: You probably forgot to install an OOB. Use Jexus Manager to reproduce the error, and it provides more information on what's wrong, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html#detailed-error-message-by-jexus-manager

Comment: According to your description, I guess you may not allow the administrator to access your web.config file. I suggest you could right click the web application folder and check its security to make sure the administrator has the perission to access it.

Comment: Full Permissions are given to web.config file.

Comment: Is the file name your IIS web site's web.config file? I suggest you could try to create a new web site to check if this issue happened again.